# Deleted all photos/apps on iPhone 4s but settings shows 3.1 GB of photo storage used

Tags: ios, iphone, photos, storage

I am trying to get the iOS 8.3 update on my iPhone 4s and I have deleted *all* my apps and photos including the recently deleted. I then went to my settings and my non-existent 'photos' are taking up 3.1 GB of my storage. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been caused by a bug in iOS 8. I had the same problem and just now solved it by doing the following:

1. Go to **Settings**, then **General,** then **Date & Time.**

   2. Untoggle "**Set Automatically**". (We'll toggle it on again in the end.)
   3. Set the time several months back in time. I set it a year back.
   4. Go to the **Photos** app. The **Recently Deleted** album will still say that it has 0 photos, but if you actually open it, you may see that there are actually many in there! You can then click "delete all" and you will have cleared up that space.
   5. You can now go to **Usage** in settings to see that space has been cleared up. If there is still some, try setting the time back and forward and see if you discover more photos in the **Recently Deleted** album.

That worked for me. I cleared up 8GB of "deleted" hidden photos.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove the camera roll backup from the iCloud (and then add it back again).  This is to "recalibrate" the iCloud.

Slide the switch from green to white and give it the "ok" to remove photos from the cloud.

Next, step out of that menu and then step back into it and re-activate the switch to backup the camera roll to the cloud.

Then, run a backup and it should free up a bunch of space and recalibrate the size of your camera roll.

PS. Apple will fix this one day.....